# Convert to []byte Golang

Tags: go

I have a use case where I have the code as below. I have a request coming in to hit the backend where I need to append data to a map. My question is how do I convert the below type to a []byte to unmarshal?
Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
type Example struct {
    Category string `json:"category"`
    Name     string `json:"name"`
}
```

Incoming Postman request json looks like this:
`[{"Category":"TestCategory", "Name":"Sample1"}]`
but after doing
 `jsonString Type: []Example`
`if err := gc.ShouldBindJSON(&jsonString)` it looks like `[{TestCategory Sample1}]` ; how do I convert this to a `[]byte`?

```
for _, req := range blob{
    var jsonString Example
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &blob); err != nil { //this does not work
            logger.Fatal(err)
    }

    //I am checking if a key-value is present and appending it to the map
    dict := make(map[string][]Example)
    dict[req.Category] = append(dict[req.Category], req)
    fmt.Println(dict)
    if value, ok := dict["TestCategory"]; ok {
        fmt.Printf("Found %d\n", value)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("not found")
    }
}

//I was able to test the above logic by declaring the jsonString as a const and it works
```

Comment: I'm afraid `[{TestCategory Sample1}]` is not valid json, can you please try to fix your question by providing the actual json you're trying to unmarshal? Also it wouldn't hurt if you would re-format the code in the question so that it is readable.

Comment: @mkopriva- made the change, does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes, it makes a bit more sense now, what is the type of the `jsonString` variable which you then pass to `ShouldBindJSON`? It would be best if you include that part of the code as well.

Comment: Note that inside the loop you are re-declaring the `dict` variable each iteration, so you're not really "appending" anything to the map but instead creating a map with a single element and then discarding it when the iteration exits.

Comment: made the change it is of type `jsonString Type: []Example`

Comment: And can I assume that the `blob` variable in the `range` statement holds that `[]Example` that you've unmarshaled using `ShouldBindJSON` into `jsonString`?

Comment: Yes essentially the blob variable is of the same type as jsonString and they both have the same value of `[{TestCategory Sample1}]`

Comment: Another thing to note is that `[{TestCategory Sample1}]` is the default print format of a `[]Example` value, if you need more details in the print output you'll need to explicitly use the corresponding "verbs", like `%+v` or `%#v`. If I understood you correctly you're trying to map examples by category in which case you can do something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/AqvtIFR0N94)?

Comment: @mkopriva- thanks for the example. That is what I am trying to do. Appreciate you explaining every piece of it as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two directions in which you can move the data:

- from JSON to a Go data structure

```golang
    // This is your payload coming from the request.
    jsonStr := `[{"Category":"TestCategory", "Name":"Sample1"}]`

    // This is the Go struct that will hold the unmarshalled data.
    var examples []Example
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &examples)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Examples:", examples) // prints "Examples: [{TestCategory Sample1}]"
```

- from a Go data structure to JSON (either `string` or `[]byte`)

```golang
    exampleBytes, err := json.Marshal(examples)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Example bytes:", string(exampleBytes)) // prints "Example bytes: [{"category":"TestCategory","name":"Sample1"}]"
```

You should check out "Go by Example" if you haven't already: https://gobyexample.com/json

Looking at your code:

- You are looping on `blob` but instead of using the `req` you are trying to unmarshal onto the entire `blob` each time. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve there but nothing good can come out of changing a struct you're looping over from within the loop.
- The request JSON you are listing is an array of JSON objects. You are trying to unmarshal that into a single `Example` struct. That won't work, you need an array of those.